# RStudio server source bash script with environment variables prior to startup

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio, intel-mkl, rstudio-server

How can I get RStudio server to source a bash script prior to starting a R session?

I have read 
https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/
and tried to source a bash script in the `Renviron` shell script, but no success.

Background: I compiled R from source with intel MKL available as a shared library.
The `R` binary will fail to start with the following message:

```
/opt/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

unless

```
echo 'source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64'>>/etc/profile.d/rmkl.sh
```

is set, i.e. some environment variables are sourced prior to starting R from bash.

However, RStudio server is not applying these and failing with:

```
Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox systemd: Starting RStudio Server...
    Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox systemd: Started RStudio Server.
    Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox rserver[22411]: ERROR R did not return any output when queried for directory location information; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::r_util::<unnamed>::detectRLocationsUsingR(const std::string&, rstudio::core::FilePath*, rstudio::core::FilePath*, rstudio::core::config_utils::Variables*, std::string*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/r_util/REnvironmentPosix.cpp:483
    Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox rserver[22411]: ERROR system error 71 (Protocol error) [description=Unable to parse version from R, version-info=, r-error=/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory|||]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::r_util::rVersion(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const std::string&, std::string*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/r_util/REnvironmentPosix.cpp:784; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::r_util::detectREnvironment(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const std::string&, std::string*, std::string*, rstudio::core::r_util::EnvironmentVars*, std::string*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/r_util/REnvironmentPosix.cpp:678
```

**How can I also get RStudio server to load the variables properly?**

> Note: I am using centos 7.4 with the following installation instructions for R and RStudio Server:

```
# ad a fast BLAS library. openblas is another good alternative to MKL
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo
rpm --import https://yum.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB
yum -y update
yum -y install intel-mkl-64bit

# get R build dependencies
yum-builddep -y R

# download sources
R_VERSION="3.4.3"
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xvf R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
rm -f R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
mkdir /opt/R
mv R-${R_VERSION} /opt/R/${R_VERSION}
cd /opt/R/${R_VERSION}

# turn on some optimizations https://wbnicholson.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/linking-r-with-intels-math-kernel-libraries/
# build R from source
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
echo 'source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64'>>/etc/profile.d/rmkl.sh
chown vagrant /home/vagrant/.Renviron

MKL="-Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -Wl,--start-group -lmkl_gnu_thread  -lmkl_core  -Wl,--end-group -fopenmp  -ldl -lpthread -lm"
./configure --prefix=/opt/R/${R_VERSION} --with-blas="$MKL" --with-cairo --with-lapack --enable-R-shlib
make
# check that all worked fine
ldd bin/exec/R
# install
make install
ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /bin/R
```

and then add RStudio server:

```
# add rstudio server
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.419-x86_64.rpm
yum install -y --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.419-x86_64.rpm
rm -f rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.419-x86_64.rpm

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl status rstudio-server.service
```

Comment: Compiling `R` from source with `Intel MKL` is *not* a trivial task and can require a lot of work and debugging to get it right. I think your problem lies in that step - the `.Renviron` file is meant really just for setting environment variables, and the `.Rprofile` that comes afterwards contains R code already. Btw, you may want to use `Renviron.site`

Comment: Compiling with mkl with the script above was a breeze. Only the link options might require further tuning to the actual processor being used. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Creating  `/opt/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/etc/Renviron.site` with contents of: `source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64` does not fix the problem.

Comment: The Renviron.site was meant as a general remark, not that I think it could fix this particular problem. Experienced professionals easily spend one or more days investigating and adjusting the flags for specific setup / OS

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem [from the documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/r-sessions.html) it seems as if setting environment variables was only supported in the *Pro* version of RStudio Server.

Comment: no, I, unfortunately, did not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I compiled R using the same MKL libraries and I couldn't compile some packages in Rstudio Desktop (sorry, not server). So, I put the same environment variables that mklvars.sh sets in a `~/.Renviron`. You can try this way:

```
env > env_no_mkl.txt
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
env > env_mkl.txt
diff env_no_mkl.txt env_mkl.txt | egrep '^>' | awk '{print $2}' >> ~/.Renviron
```

After that you'll have some ENV_VAR=values... at the end of your `~/.Renviron`. I'm not sure if all of them are needed.